# What's the difference between "... you have completed the task" and "... you completed the task"?

Tags: meaning, differences, past-tense, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

Is there any difference in the meaning of the following sentences? Or do they mean the exact same thing?

> By doing both, you have completed the task.
>
> By doing both, you completed the task.

Comment: The second does not "sound" right.

Comment: Not sure if "By doing both..." changes the situation. Shouldn't the real Q be if "You have completed the task" is any different from "You completed the task"?

Comment: Is there a difference? I'm not sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the present-perfect (have completed) *only when* the action has bearing upon  present circumstances.  The present perfect is ungrammatical if the action was completed in the past and has no bearing whatsoever upon present circumstances.

For example:

When you were ten years old (now you're in your 30s, say) you were in the Boy Scouts and back then you wanted to earn a merit badge on Morse Code.  There were two prerequisite tasks: 1) demonstrate knowledge of Morse Code by converting a message in dots and dashes into letters and words and 2) send a text message in Morse Code to another person.

**By completing both tasks, you *earned* the merit badge.**

It would be ungrammatical to say to you, now in your 30s, when speaking of that specific accomplishment achieved in your childhood:

**By completing both tasks, you *have earned* the merit badge.** [wrong tense]

However, the scout master might very well say to a boy scout in his troop:

**Congratulations! By completing both tasks, you *have earned* the Morse Code merit badge.**

On the other hand, the simple past tense (earned) can be used for *both* scenarios. The scout master could say to a boy scout in his troop:

**Congratulations! By completing both tasks, you earned the Morse Code merit badge.**

Although "have earned" would be more precise there, employing the simple past in situations where the present perfect would be more appropriate is far less jarring than employing the present-perfect in situations where the present perfect is inappropriate.  That's because the present perfect implies that the action expressed has relevance to present circumstances; the sentence becomes "dissonant" if there is no such relevance.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on context. Present Perfect *(have completed)* implies a strong connection between the past activity and the present time. If the task was completed long ago, and/or has no special relevance to the time of speaking/writing, use Simple Past. Consider...

> 1: *By dancing naked on the table-top just now you annoyed me.*
>    2: *By dancing naked on the table-top last year you annoyed me.*
>    3: *By dancing naked on the table-top just now you have annoyed me.*
>    4: *By dancing naked on the table-top last year you have annoyed me.*

...where it's implicit in both #1 and #2 that the speaker is no longer annoyed, since if she *was*, she'd have used #3 or (an unforgiving speaker in relatively unusual circumstances) #4.

Comment: Yes, a better example was preferable. However ...

Comment: Wasn't @hellenaaa asking about that specific sentence?

Comment: @Huey: The fact that I chose different words is largely irrelevant. OP's specific sentences are affected in the same way. The Present Perfect version can *only* refer to a recent task, the completion of which is relevant to time of utterance. The only difference is that OP's Simple Past version *could in principle* apply whether the fact of completion is still "relevant" or not, so I chose different words for an example that makes the difference more obvious.

Comment: @Edwin: What's with the "however"? Should I maybe change it to *By refusing to change my example, I [have] annoyed Edwin?* :)

Comment: 'Present perfect' jars with the content 'dancing naked on the table-top'. Perhaps it's just me, though.

Comment: @Edwin: I think perhaps it's just you, but I'm unclear as to whether you have misgivings about the grammar or the semantics. Would *By giving me your last Rolo you have won my heart* be any better from your point of view? From *my* point of view I'd be much happier with Present Perfect there, since it would be a serious waste of *any* Rolo (let alone my *last* one) to have given it to someone whose ardent gratitude wasn't continuously "true and relevant" until the end of time. :)

Comment: You'll be suggesting a bare infinitive next.

Comment: @Edwin: I could get behind ***To suggest** such a thing would annoy/would have annoyed me*, but I suppose the ***to*** there makes that a "marked infinitive". Can I get away with *By making me **suggest** this example, I [have] annoyed him* ?!